# How to deploy a CoAP server written using libcoap in c/c++ on k8's behind a load balancer

Tags: kubernetes, cloud, coap, dtls, libcoap

I started to code a CoAP server in c/c++ using libcoap. I was really interested in CoAP features such as Multicasting, Observability and DTLS CID. I was hoping that I could deploy my server on a cloud service and or using k8's so I can run it behind a load balancer in a scalable manner.

However, at some point during writing the code, it occurred to me that some of the previously mentioned needs perhaps deliberate routing of client requests to servers. For example to use DTLS CID and have context aware sessions.

I came across a Java implementation of CoAP called Eclipse Californium that seems to support what I am after in these examples:

[Eclipse Californium server deployment with k8's example](https://github.com/eclipse-californium/californium/tree/main/demo-apps/cf-extplugtest-server)

I was hoping anyone would potentially know if this is possible for a libcoap server? Or perhaps point me to examples? Any help or guidance is really appreciated.

Comment: I guess, nobody else has implemented something similar for libcoap/mbedtls. But maybe it's in the meantime interesting enough to ask k8s about something as a UDP-load-balancer based on CID.